# Extract anything that looks like links from large amount of data in python

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, hyperlink

I have around 5 GB of html data which I want to process to find links to a set of websites and perform some additional filtering. Right now I use simple regexp for each site and iterate over them, searching for matches. In my case links can be outside of "a" tags and be not well formed in many ways(like "\n" in the middle of link) so I try to grab as much "links" as I can and check them later in other scripts(so no BeatifulSoup\lxml\etc). The problem is that my script is pretty slow, so I am thinking about any ways to speed it up. I am writing a set of test to check different approaches, but hope to get some advices :)

Right now I am thinking about getting all links without filtering first(maybe using C module or standalone app, which doesn't use regexp but simple search to get start and end of every link) and then using regexp to match ones I need.

Comment: have you tried to parallelize this using multiple process?

Comment: yes, I use Queue module to parse as much data as my CPU can handle

Comment: Get a faster CPU.

Sorry... I couldn't resist.

Comment: Unfortunantly I need to work with quite old hardware and can't do anything about it.

Comment: How long does it take? 5GB isn't that much after all and parsing using regexp should be as fast as reading. You are probably blocked on IO not on cpu.

Comment: Bunch of 2GB RAM / 2GHz CPU servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways out.

- Parallelise
- Profile your code to see where the bottleneck is. The result are often surprising.
- Use a single regexp (concatenate using |) rather than multiple ones.